# What is the proper way to set up Node.js and MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I currently have a Node server that handles several API calls. This server is called by a React App running on a front-end server. As of right now I don't have a database but I am in the process of integrating MySQL to this project. I've seen there is Node support for MySQL so I was wondering which was the proper way to set this up.
Should I run another server for the database or is my API server able to do handle MySQL as well?

Comment: It depends  on parameters of server where Your code is running. For example: I've server with 8 cores and 32gb ram from OVH or Hetzner. I just keep both app and db on same server to avoid network i/o when my app does query to database. But I understand that when my business will grow I've to separate database and app to different servers for load balancing, horizontal scalability and etc. reasons. Btw for start You can take 2 small servers (1 cpu per each) and put app to one and db to another for scalability in mind from beginning. (:   p.s. DigitalOcean gives coupon code: `DROPLET10` - 10$ ex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found this answer at this link:

https://www.quora.com/Should-a-REST-API-for-a-database-be-hosted-on-the-same-or-a-separate-server

Essentially:

> It depends on the architecture of the system you are working with or
>   are trying to build.
>
> If the setup is a REST API accessing a single database instance
>   (non-distributed, non-replicated setup), having both hosted on the
>   same server should be fine. If the REST API’s sole purpose is to
>   abstract queries and operations against this single database, the
>   same-server approach is justified. This approach is also suggested
>   provided your API isn’t being hammered by a substantial amount of
>   consumers.
>
> On the other hand, if you are dealing with a distributed database
>   setup (or with replication), then there would be a notion of load
>   balancing to deal with scalability / responsiveness. In this setup, it
>   would make most sense to have your REST API hosted on a separate
>   server with proper failover mechanisms (e.g. load balancing across “n”
>   servers dedicated to hosting the API).